# How can I layout my dialog => scroll view => expandable list view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a dialog box in my Android app to let the user change some options.

My plan for the layout for this dialog box is:

- Dialog

  - ScrollView wrapping all the options

    - Option group 1 - ExpandableListView
    - Option group 2 - as above
    - Top level option A - CheckedTextView
    - Top level option B - CheckedTextView
    - Top level option C - CheckedTextView
  - OK / Cancel buttons

But, when I try and get the layout right I end up with either the option groups collapsed so that the ExpandableListView has only as much height as the first group, or the ExpandableListView taking up the entire dialog, or similar.

In the below screenshot you can see my dialog, with the option groups in blue (only one showing), top level options in green, unused ScrollView space in red and the OK / cancel LinearLayout in white.

[image: Screenshot of bad layout]

## refine_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- ScrollView so that the user can see all the options
         Without filling the entire dialog and losing the ok / cancel buttons
         The height is hardcoded - I'd like to make it fill_parent -->
    <ScrollView
        android:background="#FFFF0000"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"> <!--RED-->

        <!-- Linear layout around the options
             ScrollView complains if it wraps multiple children -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#FF00FF00"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"> <!--GREEN-->

            <!-- Option groups -->
            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/elvRefine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FF0000FF" /> <!--BLUE-->

            <!-- Top level options -->
            <CheckedTextView
                android:id="@+id/checkboxA"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top level option A" />
            <CheckedTextView
                android:id="@+id/checkboxB"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top level option B" />
            <CheckedTextView
                android:id="@+id/checkboxC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top level option C" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <!-- OK, cancel buttons -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right"> <!--WHITE-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

## getRefineDialog()

```
private Dialog getRefineDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.refine_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Refine options");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    final ExpandableListView elv = 
                (ExpandableListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.elvRefine);
    elv.setAdapter(new RefineAdapter(this));
    elv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    // cancel button listener
    Common.setSimpleCancelListener(dialog, R.id.buttonCancel);
    return dialog;
}
```

The [ExpandableListView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) says that:

> You cannot use the value wrap_content for the android:layout_height attribute of a ExpandableListView in XML if the parent's size is also not strictly specified (for example, if the parent were ScrollView you could not specify wrap_content since it also can be any length. However, you can use wrap_content if the ExpandableListView parent has a specific size, such as 100 pixels.

...but I didn't think that should be a problem, because the ScrollView has a fixed height of 300dp (or the fixed height of the dialog if the parent dialog is set to match_parent).

Is there an easy way to get this layout working properly? If not, how should I represent an options menu with both option groups and top level options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since seen a lot of arguments that putting one scrollable view inside another scrollable view just doesn't work. I'm pretty sure this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Use PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment in new code. This way you won't reinvent the wheel and your app will fit in with others on the platform.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out, I'm new to Android and glad to learn about them. In this case, the dialog is for refining search options - e.g. the user searches by text, and then clicks a "refine options" button. In one category they can tick states (e.g. Alberta, British Columbia, Manitoba) to restrict the search to those states, and they can tick other checkboxes to restrict search results similarly. I suspect that these classes aren't appropriate for non-permanent / non-"settings" type things - is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider redoing this part of your application, having so much content in a dialog is going to confuse the user. The dialog is meant for short and simple answers, not complex ones.

My suggestion is change your design approach.

Comment: I can put the same layout in a new activity, but then I just have the same problem in a bigger window => http://i.imgur.com/Sa8OG.jpg.